# how to use conditional statement in react and then setState inside if condition if not why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I have watched some tutorials of react and many people don't really use a conditional statement to `setState` but when I try to `setState` inside an if statement it works fine and really makes the work easy. What could be the problems with this simple approach?

As a beginner to **React**, I am working on this dummy/practice **Expense tracker project** and is working perfectly but I am still not clear why not to use **hooks inside if condition**  ** I have setstate inside if condition**  and how to avoid it because if statements are extremely important in every programming language.

**here is a piece of my  stupid code**

**CHECK THE LINE sethistory(parsedData)**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let retrieveData = localStorage.getItem(keyFor);
    let parseData = JSON.parse(retrieveData);
    if (parseData) {
      getDynamicCal(parseData);
      sethistory(parseData);
    } else {
      sethistory([]);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: If you check the docs on `Rules of Hooks` it's the first thing they print, in bold **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level** https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html. You can find out more there

Comment: You might want to add an example (as code). As you can see from the other comments, it's not clear whether you mean the call to the updater (`setState`) or the initial call to `useState`.

Comment: @Yoshi i have added a piece of code kindly check  it ,  my questions is that inside if condition i have set  setHistory(parseddata) which is not the very right way accoridng to experts but i dont know why? and how to avoid it ,  btway thanks alot :)

Comment: Your question is a lot clearer now. Thanks! So, no, whatever *expert* you're citing, there's absolutely nothing wrong with calling the updater (`sethistory` in your case) inside a condition. There is a case (linked above 3 times) where it's important not to place initial calls to hooks (`useState(...)`, `useReducer(...)`, ...) in a condition, but this does not apply here.